# How to Set Bootstrap Image Height with relevel Div Height

Tags: html, css, gridview, bootstrap-4

What I am trying to do, don't meter what height width of the image, it will always set in the centre and div height 500px

its seems like 2nd green example

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x550" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                <h1>I am fix Div</h1>
              </div>

              <div class="col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x750" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                <h1>I am fix Div</h1>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
Bootstrap 4
```

[image]

Comment: Not really sure, what you are asking for. What do you want? That the second col, has the same height as the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `*background-size: contain;*`

This may help you for what you are looking for https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain